# Return multiple values from one method

Tags: solidity

Is something like this a good idea? I want to concatenate two values but it doesn't work.

```
function charityWallets() public view returns (address) {
    return _charityWalletAddress + " - " + _charityWalletAddress2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function charityWallets() public view returns (address, address) {
    return (_charityWalletAddress, _charityWalletAddress2);
}
```

On the receiving side, you need to handle two values. Something like this:

```
(address a, address b) = charityWallets();
```

Hope it helps.